# Shared rationals in base pi

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a theorem on rational numbers in irrational bases? For example $100$ in base $\sqrt{2}$ is $2$, so it's an integer in both bases, but are there shared integers and rationals in base $\pi$? Or even is there a polynomial evaluated at $\pi$ that comes out as a rational number?

Comment: Constant polynomial?

Comment: What are the allowed "digits" in base $\;\sqrt2\;$ , for example??

Comment: What does it mean to write a number in base $\pi$?  There aren't any integers $a_i$ such that $\sum a_i\pi^i$ is an integer (other than trivial cases).

Comment: @DonAntonio Integers, so trivially 1 is 1, and then 10 is $\sqrt{2}$ and 100 is $\sqrt{2}^2$, and so on

Comment: @Hovestar So in base $\;\pi\;$ we can use the digits $\;0,1,2,3\;$ , or what

Comment: @lulu perfect, what set of numbers is that that have that property?

Comment: @DonAntonio Arbitrary positive reals may be used as bases; [phinary is the most common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base), but any number works. The digits are nonnegative integers $<$ the base, and the $i$th digit is interpreted as base$^i$, as usual. (See e.g. [this paper](http://people.fjfi.cvut.cz/pelanedi/Publications/AmbrozArithmetics.pdf).)

Comment: The transcendental numbers.  I mean, that's the definition.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah since 4 would be expressed as $10.something$

Comment: @lulu, awesome can you make that an answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well, then you (and the OP) seem to mean non-integer bases...Never heard of it, and I just can't understand what possible uses it can have.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what it's an answer to.  You can answer your own question if you like.  The wiki article on [Transcendental Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) may be of use.

Comment: @DonAntonio Irrational bases are a specific class of non-integer bases, so there's no inaccuracy here - the OP (it sounds like) is really interested in specifically irrational bases. "I just can't understand what possible uses it can have." Fair, but that doesn't mean it's unreasonable to ask questions about it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Who said it was unreasonable? It is just weird... *for me* .